# Creating flashcards with LaTeX

Tags: positioning, page-breaking

As the current semester is almost over and [my lecturenotes-typesetting project](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents/GeoTopo) draws to a close, I start learning the definitions with flashcards. I've created the flashcards automatically with a Python script that extracts `\begin{definition}..\end{definition}` and puts them into a new `TeX`-document. In most cases, it works fine:

[image]

The TeX-file is in `A7` so that every page contains exactly one definition. To make sure that this works, I surround the definitions like this:

```
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{definition}..\end{definition}
\vspace*{\fill}
\clearpage
```

I've inserted the `\vspace*{\fill}` to center the definitions on the `A7` page. So I can print 8 definitions on `A4` pages and cut them (see image below).

This works fine for about 60 flashcards / definitions, but about 10 flashcards are either not vertically centered or have 2 definitions on one page.

Why are there pages with two definitions, when after every definition is a `\clearpage`? Is there a better way to vertically center definition environments than by surrounding them with `\vspace*{\fill}`?

(I don't think you need to look at the [Python script](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/blob/master/documents/GeoTopo/definitions/generateDefinitions.py) or the [TeX-template](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/blob/master/documents/GeoTopo/definitions/mathe-vorlage.tex), but if you want to, you can.)

Comment: Did you try adding `\topskip=0pt` before the first `\vspace*{\fill}`?

Comment: I did try it now, but the problems remained. Why should `\topskip=0pt` change anything?

Comment: A `\topskip` (usually `10pt` or similar) is added at the beginning of each page.

Comment: I've just found the `flashcards` document class. I gave it a try and found an error, but if this error can be resolved it might be the best solution.

Comment: A while ago, i made cards for learning (including a front and a rear side), which i could not get to work (using A6) for printing, but i wrote a small package (which still isn't on CTAN sadly). Your cards are german, so you might understand my small page for that project here http://www.rbergmann.info/projekte/kartei.html mabe you could combine that with your python script.

Comment: `flashcards` is nice, I couldn't get that working with any European page size, hence my approach. Tell me if you get flashcards working with A7 and how ;)

Comment: @Ronny: The problem is not `A7`, but `align`. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/158877/5645 for a MWE.

Comment: Haven't tried, but should work in my kartei-class i think.

Comment: @ronny “(which still isn't on CTAN sadly)” means “ctan hasn’t picked it up using its well-known psychic powers to spot that it exists”, or does it mean “i've not got around to submitting it ctan”?  my reading of what you write suggests “i submitted it but it was rejected”, but i don’t remember a flash-card submission for _years_.

Comment: No, that should read “I haven't had the time to provide an english manual and hence haven't submitted it yet.” My package differs from flashcards, because it uses `KOMAScript` and `TikZ` to set/arrange the cards. Maybe I'll take an approach to that sometime :)

Comment: @Ronny: Not all packages on CTAN have english manuals. See [tkz-euclide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide).

Comment: But my requirement for a good submission is, that my package should also provide an english manual.